# How to express "the best myself" in latin?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

I am currently trying to translate
"May I forge the best me"

"May I forge" seems easily translated as the present subjunctive first person "excudam". However, I can't find how to express the rest. I thought about:

"Optimum me excudam", using reflexive case

"Optimum memet mei excudam", something like "Forge from me the best of myself"

And others. What would be the best way to express this?